# Glassfish JSON failure

Tags: java, json, jersey, glassfish

I am having some difficulty with serialization of a POJO to JSON using Jersey in a RESTful application in Glassfish.

When I pass a complex POJO as an endpoint “Response”, I get this error in the Glassfish console:

> org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException:
>   MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=

By “complex” I mean that the root class contains many classes and many classes extend base classes.

I have figured out the following rules when passing a POJO to Jersey:

1) All classes must have an empty constructor
2) Any inner classes must be static
3) Any inner classes must be uniquely named throughout the tree from the base class

What would be great is if Jersey would tell me more. What is it finding in the POJO that it is rejecting? Is there a way to have Jersey log the specific problem or problems to the Glassfish console that it is finding in the POJO passed back to Response? Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using a simple POJO with `getter` and `setter` methods?

Comment: Is the POJO annotated with `@XmlRootElement`?

Comment: Arpit: The POJO used to serialize without any problem. As I add complexity it fails. Sometimes I back off and slowly add the code until it fails then I see a problem an it runs fine. What I need is for Jersey to tell me more specific details about what it is rejecting.

Comment: Peeskillet: That annotation is not necessary. The POJO serializes fine until I make some change to the complexity. What I need is more detail from Jersey as to why it is rejected. Any idea as to how to get Jersey to give more detail when the POJO is rejected?

Answer (score 0):

Found a work-around (sort-of):

```
JAXBContext context;
try {
    context=JAXBContext.newInstance(<myclass>);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller=context.createUnmarshaller();
    unmarshaller.setEventHandler(
        new javax.xml.bind.helpers.DefaultValidationEventHandler());
    } 
catch (JAXBException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

When it throws there is a list that goes to the console describing any issues. The problem is that this JAXBContext is not as modern as the one used in Jersey. It lists problems that are not (like annotating a member of an Interface). I scanned through the errors (there were 14 in my case) and 13 were regarding annotating interface members. The 14th was the interesting one which I fixed and all works fine now.